# Free alternative to RegexBuddy

Tags: regex

Are there any good alternatives that support writing regexps in different flavors and allow you to test them?

Comment: not exact dupe. but is very similar to other regex tools topic

Comment: See also https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/free-program-to-create-regular-expressions-with-a-gui

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here's a list of the Regex tools mentioned across the threads:

[Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/)

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

[.NET Regular Expression Designer](http://www.netregex.com/)

[Regex-Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/)

[larsolavtorvik online tool](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/)

[Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/)

[Regular Expression Workbench](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2003/07/07/52362.aspx)

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)

[Reggy](https://github.com/samsouder/reggy/)

[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Do any of these tools allow regexes to be translated to different dialects (e. g., translating a Java regex to a JavaScript regex, and vice-versa?) I know that RegexBuddy has this feature, but I want to know whether there are others with this feature as well.

Comment: Forgot the name of my favorite regex tool (installing new machine), which was the Regex-coach as it seems. Thanks!

Comment: Too bad practical questions like these aren't permitted anymore, but "do my homework while I watch a movie" type questions are. That said, in 2018, desktop applications have gone the way of the dodo, so I recommend https://regex101.com/. It shows the time taken as well the number of steps. It also offers a ton of customizations.

Comment: The question was technically answered, but the majority of these tools are very old (not updated). Not to say they are completely useless. At least RegExBuddy is updated regularly, and can do conversions to other languages, and explains each search step in layman's English. @AbhijitSarkar [RegEx101.com](https://RegEx101.com) is next closest thing; includes a replacement/substitution checker also.  Also, [softwarerecs SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/free-program-to-create-regular-expressions-with-a-gui) allows software recommendations.

Comment: Expresso is just a trial.

Comment: Expresso is just a trial.

Comment: well regular expressions have not changed much so if the tool did the job it still does it

Answer (score 12):

The excellent and free [Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/) doesn't appear in the list above but it's certainly worth a look at.

Support for different "flavours" is limited but as far as writing and testing actual regular expressions is concerned it's good and the in-built help is very useful too.

Comment: Appears to be dead now :(

Comment: This is my favorite Regex tool. I found a link for it here: http://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/1.4/

Answer (score 5):

Expresso is way up there on my list.

Comment: 9 years later, I stumbled upon your answer, and I'm loving Expresso ! Thanks a bunch :)