# Generate a valid example value for a xs:pattern

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, design-patterns

I have the following xsd restriction:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="25"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="26"/>
        <xs:pattern value="(SA|DA|NT|DCS)(((0[1-9]|1[0-9])9999999999\d{4}\d{7})|([2-3]0(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])\d{8}\d{4}\d{7})|(4099999999(0[1-9]|1[0-9])\d{4}\d{7}))"/>
    </xs:restriction>
```

The problem is that im not able to generate an example value that complies with this pattern...is there some program or website where inputting the pattern it gives out valid example values for the pattern?

I used liquid xml studio in order to generate a sample xml with the schema and it got wrong all the strings that were validated by patterns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, because you asked for it:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833197.aspx
2. http://code.google.com/p/xeger/

Comment: Thanks for the tools and sorry for the delay ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could try any regular expression tool such as the ones foound here [Free alternative to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132405/free-alternative-to-regxbuddy)

<strike>I think you are missing a bracket</strike> (**EDIT** Oh I copied it wrong, now updated to show your expression:-))

(SA|DA|NT|DCS)(((0[1-9]|1[0-9])9999999999\d{4}\d{7})|([2-3]0(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])\d{8}\d{4}\d{7})|(4099999999(0[1-9]|1[0-9])\d{4}\d{7}))

Here are a few matches to get you started

```
SA11999999999944447777777
DA01999999999944447777777
NT20498888888844447777777
```

Try Expresso, it will help you. It doesn't generate the expressions, but it explains in plain English what is required.

Comment: The expression is as is in the original xsd given to me so if its wrong...something is very wrong :S

Comment: Tried all the regular expression tools...none of them gave me the option to generate a sample based on the expression...and inputing text semirandomly trying it to match in the tool is like searching for a grain of salt in the beach :(

Comment: They worked fine, but for now i cant give you the answer as correct becouse we need primarily the tool to generate the valid values as we have a lot of regex expressions to fill with valid values :S... Another one: (HRI|MAG|DAP)[0-2]((0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])\d{8})\d{4}\d{6}