# Reg Expression Validation on a String

Tags: java

Can I use Reg Expression for the following use case?

I Need to write a boolean method which takes a String parameter that should satisfy following conditions.

- 20 character length string.
- First 9 characters will be a number
- Next 2 characters will be alphabets
- Next 2 characters will be a number.(1 to 31 or 99)
- Next 1 character will be an alphabet
- Last 6 characters will be a number.

In this, I have wrote the code for the first requirement:
**[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}** - This expression works well for the first case. I don't know how to write a complete reg expression to meet the entire requirement.
Please help.

Comment: This seems like homework. Have you looked at free regex editors like mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132405/free-alternative-to-regxbuddy to help you create your regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use regexes for this.

Ignore the "20 characters" part and describe a string created by concatenating 9 digits, 2 letters, 2 digits, 1 letter and another digit.

- Start with the string start: `^`
- Then 9 digits. The `\d` conveniently describes the character set `[0-9]`, so `\d{9}` means "nine digits"
- Then 2 letters. The `\w` class is too broad, so stick to `[a-zA-Z]` for a letter.
- Then another two digits. They seem to be from a restricted set, so describe the set with alternation and grouping.
- Then another letter and another digit.
- And, finally, you have to end at the end of the string: `$`

For reference, this regex means "the string is nine letters, then 12-15 or 99, then another letter":

```
^[a-zA-Z]{9}(1[2-5]|99)[a-zA-Z]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the String [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), especially the part about [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) as well as the [documentation about regular expressions in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

Your first requirement is already implicit in the remaining ones, so I would just skip it. Then, just write the regex code that matches each part one after the other:

```
[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}...
```

There is one special consideration for the number that might be 1 to 31. While it is possible to match this in one regex, it would be verbose and difficult to understand. Instead, perform basic matching in the regex and extract this part as a *capturing group* by putting it into parentheses:

```
([0-9]{2})
```

If you use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to apply your regex, and your string matches the pattern, you can then easily get at just thost two characters, use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert them to an integer (which is completely safe because you know the two characters are digits), and then check the value normally.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression takes

```
  ^[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]{2}([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|99)[a-zA-Z]([0-9]{6})$
```

takes 
9 letters at start,
Followed by 2 alphabets,
Followed by number between 1 to 31 or 99,
Followed by an alphabet,
followed by 6 digits.