# How to replace all instances of a sequence of chars inside a string

Tags: c#, string

Assuming I have a text file with the following content:

`longtextwith some space and unicode escape like this \u003ca`

I want to replace all instances / occurences / sequences of `\u003c` ignoring the fact that an `a` is trailing. Something like "look for all instances of a sequence of characters, ignore cases and replace it".

I tried this already but nothing happens:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("1.txt"))
{
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();

    result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\b\\u003c\b", "<", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

This variants also yielded not my intended result:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\\u003c", "<", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
result = Regex.Replace(result, "\u003c", "<", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
result = Regex.Replace(result, "\b\\u003c\b", "<", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

In Lua this works: `str = string.gsub(str, '\\u003e', '>')`

In this case I am not interested in the options provided by .NET framework for encoding and decoding of unicode, ascii etc.

Comment: Use a RegEx editor tool that allow you debug your RegEx pattern. The problem must be in the Pattern. e.g. you have double \\ while using @ . See this answer on SO if you don't want to buy RegExBuddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132405/free-alternative-to-regxbuddy

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `String.Replace`?

```
string str = inputString.Replace("\\u003c", "<");
```

If you want a case-insensitive replace, try this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@" \\u003c", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string str = regex.Replace(inputString, "<");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should be @"\b\u003c". Since you defined it with @, you do not need a double backslash in front of the u003c. Also, \b means a word boundary, so your current pattern will not match a trailing a because it is not then on a word boundary.

For further reference, check out the RegEx.Escape method which helps to ensure your pattern is properly escaped. If you are working with Regular Expressions very often, do yourself a favor and check out www.RegExBuddy.com. I purchased it several years ago and love it. It is a great tool and inexpensive to boot.